# jquery div click with data

Tags: jquery

this is my code

```
<a href="#" id="ref" data-post="5">Test<i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
<a href="#" id="ref" data-post="1">Test1<i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#ref').on('click', function(e) {
       var post_id = $(this).data('post');
       e.preventDefault();
       alert(post_id);
    });

});
```

[My code on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WF6H6/1/)

Why when i click on Test works but when i click on Test1 don't works?

Thank's in advanced.
Aesis.

Comment: you can't have the same ID. ID is meant to be unique

Answer (score 4):

**ID must be unique for each DOM element.**

So try adding `class` for elements that will work.

**Example**

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="ref" data-post="5">Test<i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
<a href="#" class="ref" data-post="1">Test1<i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.ref').on('click', function(e)
{
    var post_id = $(this).data('post');
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(post_id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

ID is meant to be unique, change it to classes if you want to use the same identifier.

if you change the `id="ref"` to `class="ref"`, then select `$('.ref')` it'll work

Answer (score 1):

Instead making same multiple ids which is invalid try with changing the id property to class:

```
 <a href="#" class="ref" data-post="5">Test<i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
 <a href="#" class="ref" data-post="1">Test1<i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
```

with this jQuery:

```
$('.ref').on('click', function(e) {
   var post_id = $(this).data('post');
   e.preventDefault();
   alert(post_id);
});
```

#### [SEE THE WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WF6H6/2/)

Note:

What happens if you use same id for multiple elements on same page is that when it gets first of them it works while others are been ignored. That's where it fails.